# Can I use Instagram login with AWS Amplify cognito in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, authentication, instagram, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Can I use Instagram login with [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) Cognito in a React Native app?

Would I be able to authenticate the app using Instagram in cognito (AWS Amplify)?

Comment: What is "Cognito in" / "in cognito"? [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)? Or something else? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63026919/edit), not here in comments.

Comment: Amazon cognito only.